# Calculate elapsed time between 2 datetime ("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS-05:00") columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

The problem I am trying to solve is that I have 2 POSIXct variable in it (start and end ). Each row is categorized and I want to get the time differences between each row for each level.

My data will be like

```
category        start                              end                    level  
a         2018-03-26T11:13:43.5-05:00      2018-03-26T11:13:44.5-05:00      1  
a         2018-03-26T11:13:45.5-05:00      2018-03-26T11:13:46.5-05:00      2  
a         2018-03-26T11:13:48.5-05:00      2018-03-26T11:13:48.5-05:00      3
```

For level 1 it is always zero as there is no preceeding row for that category.
For level 2 the elapsed time should be 
2018-03-26T11:13:45.5-05:00 (start if level 2)  -   2018-03-26T11:13:44.5-05:00 (end of level 1)
The same way for level 3 it is difference of start of level 3 and end of level 2
Expected output:

```
category   start                                end                 level   diff  
a         2018-03-26T11:13:43.5-05:00    2018-03-26T11:13:44.5-05:00  1      0  
a         2018-03-26T11:13:45.5-05:00    2018-03-26T11:13:46.5-05:00  2      1  
a         2018-03-26T11:13:48.5-05:00    2018-03-26T11:13:48.5-05:00  3      2
```

The diff is in seconds.

Can anyone help me to solve this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `lag`.  It will allow you to compare values behind the current value. here is an example:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(diff = start - lag(end))
```

Note: This will default to NA for the initial value but you can set that to 0 with 
    `df$diff[1] <- 0`